# Why is Python writing to my CSV file from the second row onward?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to create a list of values and later be able to read, sort and search them later. Although when I write to my csv file, it skips the first line and prints on the next.

I've looked all over for the solution internally and externally but nothing helps.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

window=Tk()

def show_entry_fields():
    with open('shoplist.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        list = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        list.writerow([ "%s" % (e3.get()) "%s" % (e4.get()), "%s" % (e5.get())])

Button(window, text='Add', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=3)

v = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window)
e4 = Entry(window)
e5 = Entry(window)
e3.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
e4.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
e5.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

l3 = Label(window, text = "Name:")
l3.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
l4 = Label(window, text = "Location:")
l4.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
l5 = Label(window, text = "Rate /5:")
l5.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
```

Comment: You probably already have the csv file existing on your system, with a empty line in it?

Instead of using with open('shoplist.csv', 'a') as csvfile:, change 'a' to 'wb'.

Comment: That returns the error "'str' does not support the buffer interface'

Plus I want to append the data I'm entering.

Comment: Your code (comma is missing after `(e3.get())` ) works as expected on my machine. Have you tried to delete `shoplist.csv` and run again?